# Merge the leaf nodes of a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
[
    {"name":"Central", "children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"280045.5306"},
            {"name":"Eraser","actual":"498573.6182"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"416966.6079"},
            {"name":"File Separator","actual":"341453.1982"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"441006.1289"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"510146.4382"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"473490.531"},
            {"name":"Pencil","actual":"434863.2197"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"240269.3482"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"390286.7631"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"354810.4425"},
            {"name":"Binder","actual":"265175.8668"},
            {"name":"Pen","actual":"317393.0596"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"408288.2822"},
            {"name":"Desk","actual":"257741.0409"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"East","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"427724.7033"},
            {"name":"Eraser","actual":"283530.3063"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"329089.8983"},
            {"name":"File Separator","actual":"460416.1605"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"425006.3076"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"276329.3347"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"399136.3072"},
            {"name":"Pencil","actual":"424461.6597"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"258109.7709"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"392767.9425"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"434866.8226"},
            {"name":"Binder","actual":"380534.8307"},
            {"name":"Pen","actual":"513689.1382"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"398575.9822"},
            {"name":"Desk","actual":"265480.7438"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"North","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"388682.872"},
            {"name":"Eraser","actual":"435463.3097"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"483667.7923"},
            {"name":"File Separator","actual":"408848.6072"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"332231.4176"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"182571.9238"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"479190.0605"},
            {"name":"Pencil","actual":"392142.5113"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"381062.6207"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"324673.6576"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"265853.0888"},
            {"name":"Binder","actual":"472839.831"},
            {"name":"Pen","actual":"298766.3142"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"442401.6033"},
            {"name":"Desk","actual":"271562.3788"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"South","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"271934.7238"},
            {"name":"Eraser","actual":"314152.7905"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"401729.4913"},
            {"name":"File Separator","actual":"276306.4156"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"514397.6782"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"325500.2755"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"299182.0392"},
            {"name":"Pencil","actual":"434263.1176"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"374729.1889"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"272068.4668"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"456927.7939"},
            {"name":"Binder","actual":"279658.7256"},
            {"name":"Pen","actual":"291560.4142"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"425946.2679"},
            {"name":"Desk","actual":"275949.7598"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"West","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"293676.3822"},
            {"name":"Eraser","actual":"300944.9422"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"402757.272"},
            {"name":"File Separator","actual":"453933.4533"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"276202.7374"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"366344.7989"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"249137.3409"},
            {"name":"Pencil","actual":"401176.3963"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"320504.3094"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"426531.8979"},
            {"name":"Binder","actual":"487622.6866"},
            {"name":"Pen","actual":"425276.2638"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"359071.3707"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"374215.8589"},
            {"name":"Desk","actual":"239416.5939"}
        ]
    }
]
```

The first array has the `actual` property while the second one has the `value` property. I would like this merge it into one.

```
[
    {"name":"Central","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2171.99"},
            {"name":"Eraser","value":"2110.99"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2135.99"},
            {"name":"File Separator","value":"2098.99"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2021.99"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2159.99"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2182.99"},
            {"name":"Pencil","value":"2173.99"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"1476.99"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2062.99"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"1962.99"},
            {"name":"Binder","value":"2115.99"},
            {"name":"Pen","value":"2073.99"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2185.99"},
            {"name":"Desk","value":"2096.99"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"East","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2039.99"},
            {"name":"Eraser","value":"2063.99"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2022.99"},
            {"name":"File Separator","value":"2010.99"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2111.99"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2183.99"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2136.99"},
            {"name":"Pencil","value":"2121.99"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2099.99"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2172.99"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2160.99"},
            {"name":"Binder","value":"2162.99"},
            {"name":"Pen","value":"2174.99"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2133.99"},
            {"name":"Desk","value":"2138.99"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"North","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2015.99"},
            {"name":"Eraser","value":"2176.99"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2068.99"},
            {"name":"File Separator","value":"2188.99"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2153.99"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","value":"1470.99"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2092.99"},
            {"name":"Pencil","value":"2126.99"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2165.99"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2104.99"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2141.99"},
            {"name":"Binder","value":"2179.99"},
            {"name":"Pen","value":"2155.99"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2109.99"},
            {"name":"Desk","value":"2187.99"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"South","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2190.99"},
            {"name":"Eraser","value":"2020.99"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2178.99"},
            {"name":"File Separator","value":"2142.99"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2177.99"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2093.99"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2158.99"},
            {"name":"Pencil","value":"2157.99"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2189.99"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2170.99"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2094.99"},
            {"name":"Binder","value":"2168.99"},
            {"name":"Pen","value":"2103.99"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2181.99"},
            {"name":"Desk","value":"2180.99"}
        ]
    },
    {"name":"West","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2100.99"},
            {"name":"Eraser","value":"2152.99"},
            {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2088.99"},
            {"name":"File Separator","value":"2164.99"},
            {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2064.99"},
            {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2140.99"},
            {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2026.99"},
            {"name":"Pencil","value":"2175.99"},
            {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2014.99"},
            {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2184.99"},
            {"name":"Binder","value":"2163.99"},
            {"name":"Pen","value":"2151.99"},
            {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2040.99"},
            {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2186.99"},
            {"name":"Desk","value":"1928.99"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to merge the properties based on each parent so my expected output looks something like this :

```
[
    {"name":"Central","children":
        [
            {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2171.99","actual":"280045.5306"},
            {"name":"Eraser","value":"2110.99","actual":"498573.6182"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that they always will have the same structure, try this

```js
var first = [
  {"name":"Central", "children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"280045.5306"},
      {"name":"Eraser","actual":"498573.6182"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"416966.6079"},
      {"name":"File Separator","actual":"341453.1982"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"441006.1289"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"510146.4382"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"473490.531"},
      {"name":"Pencil","actual":"434863.2197"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"240269.3482"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"390286.7631"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"354810.4425"},
      {"name":"Binder","actual":"265175.8668"},
      {"name":"Pen","actual":"317393.0596"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"408288.2822"},
      {"name":"Desk","actual":"257741.0409"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"East","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"427724.7033"},
      {"name":"Eraser","actual":"283530.3063"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"329089.8983"},
      {"name":"File Separator","actual":"460416.1605"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"425006.3076"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"276329.3347"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"399136.3072"},
      {"name":"Pencil","actual":"424461.6597"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"258109.7709"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"392767.9425"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"434866.8226"},
      {"name":"Binder","actual":"380534.8307"},
      {"name":"Pen","actual":"513689.1382"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"398575.9822"},
      {"name":"Desk","actual":"265480.7438"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"North","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"388682.872"},
      {"name":"Eraser","actual":"435463.3097"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"483667.7923"},
      {"name":"File Separator","actual":"408848.6072"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"332231.4176"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"182571.9238"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"479190.0605"},
      {"name":"Pencil","actual":"392142.5113"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"381062.6207"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"324673.6576"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"265853.0888"},
      {"name":"Binder","actual":"472839.831"},
      {"name":"Pen","actual":"298766.3142"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"442401.6033"},
      {"name":"Desk","actual":"271562.3788"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"South","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"271934.7238"},
      {"name":"Eraser","actual":"314152.7905"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"401729.4913"},
      {"name":"File Separator","actual":"276306.4156"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"514397.6782"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"325500.2755"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"299182.0392"},
      {"name":"Pencil","actual":"434263.1176"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"374729.1889"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"272068.4668"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"456927.7939"},
      {"name":"Binder","actual":"279658.7256"},
      {"name":"Pen","actual":"291560.4142"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"425946.2679"},
      {"name":"Desk","actual":"275949.7598"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"West","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","actual":"293676.3822"},
      {"name":"Eraser","actual":"300944.9422"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","actual":"402757.272"},
      {"name":"File Separator","actual":"453933.4533"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","actual":"276202.7374"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","actual":"366344.7989"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","actual":"249137.3409"},
      {"name":"Pencil","actual":"401176.3963"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","actual":"320504.3094"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","actual":"426531.8979"},
      {"name":"Binder","actual":"487622.6866"},
      {"name":"Pen","actual":"425276.2638"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","actual":"359071.3707"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","actual":"374215.8589"},
      {"name":"Desk","actual":"239416.5939"}
    ]
  }
];


var second = [
  {"name":"Central","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2171.99"},
      {"name":"Eraser","value":"2110.99"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2135.99"},
      {"name":"File Separator","value":"2098.99"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2021.99"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2159.99"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2182.99"},
      {"name":"Pencil","value":"2173.99"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"1476.99"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2062.99"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"1962.99"},
      {"name":"Binder","value":"2115.99"},
      {"name":"Pen","value":"2073.99"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2185.99"},
      {"name":"Desk","value":"2096.99"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"East","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2039.99"},
      {"name":"Eraser","value":"2063.99"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2022.99"},
      {"name":"File Separator","value":"2010.99"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2111.99"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2183.99"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2136.99"},
      {"name":"Pencil","value":"2121.99"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2099.99"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2172.99"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2160.99"},
      {"name":"Binder","value":"2162.99"},
      {"name":"Pen","value":"2174.99"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2133.99"},
      {"name":"Desk","value":"2138.99"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"North","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2015.99"},
      {"name":"Eraser","value":"2176.99"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2068.99"},
      {"name":"File Separator","value":"2188.99"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2153.99"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","value":"1470.99"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2092.99"},
      {"name":"Pencil","value":"2126.99"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2165.99"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2104.99"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2141.99"},
      {"name":"Binder","value":"2179.99"},
      {"name":"Pen","value":"2155.99"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2109.99"},
      {"name":"Desk","value":"2187.99"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"South","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2190.99"},
      {"name":"Eraser","value":"2020.99"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2178.99"},
      {"name":"File Separator","value":"2142.99"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2177.99"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2093.99"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2158.99"},
      {"name":"Pencil","value":"2157.99"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2189.99"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2170.99"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2094.99"},
      {"name":"Binder","value":"2168.99"},
      {"name":"Pen","value":"2103.99"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2181.99"},
      {"name":"Desk","value":"2180.99"}
    ]
  },
  {"name":"West","children":
    [
      {"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":"2100.99"},
      {"name":"Eraser","value":"2152.99"},
      {"name":"File Cabinet","value":"2088.99"},
      {"name":"File Separator","value":"2164.99"},
      {"name":"Hard Cover File","value":"2064.99"},
      {"name":"Highlighter","value":"2140.99"},
      {"name":"Office Chair","value":"2026.99"},
      {"name":"Pencil","value":"2175.99"},
      {"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":"2014.99"},
      {"name":"White Board Markers","value":"2184.99"},
      {"name":"Binder","value":"2163.99"},
      {"name":"Pen","value":"2151.99"},
      {"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":"2040.99"},
      {"name":"Pen Set","value":"2186.99"},
      {"name":"Desk","value":"1928.99"}
    ]
  }
];

var third = first.map((item, i) => {
  item.children.map((children, j) => {
    children.value = second[i].children[j].value
  })
  return item
})

console.log(third)
```